# New-ADUser : The specified account already exists At line:43 char:10

Tags: powershell, dns

hi im learning MCSE and i have a project to create 8000 users i use many different scripts and csv but all of them failed on power shell ( idk why but 1 of them working on active directroy toolkit )

this is my csv ( few of them )

```
givenName,SN,password,title,ou,group,department,company,sAMAccountName,displayname
user1,Test1,P@ssw0rd,Newbie,"OU=Projects,DC=G4,DC=com",New,Newbie,G4,UT-1,UT1
user2,Test2,P@ssw0rd,Newbie,"OU=Projects,DC=G4,DC=com",New,Newbie,G4,UT-2,UT2
user3,Test3,P@ssw0rd,Newbie,"OU=Projects,DC=G4,DC=com",New,Newbie,G4,UT-3,UT3
user4,Test4,P@ssw0rd,Newbie,"OU=Projects,DC=G4,DC=com",New,Newbie,G$,UT-4,UT4
user5,Test5,P@ssw0rd,Newbie,"OU=Projects,DC=G4,DC=com",New,Newbie,G4,UT-5,UT5
```

and my script is

```
#Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
#Author: Robert Allen
#Website: activedirectrypro.com

Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$Users = Import-csv C:\Projects\Users\Google2.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    # Read user data from each field in each row
    # the username is used more often, so to prevent typing, save that in a variable

        # create a hashtable for splatting the parameters
        $userProps = @{
            SamAccountName            = $User.SamAccountName                   
            Path                                   = $User.OU
            GivenName                       = $User.GivenName 
            Surname                           = $User.Surname
            Initials                               = $User.Initials
            Name                               = $User.sAMAccountname
            DisplayName                   = $User.DisplayName
            UserPrincipalName          = $user.UserPrincipalName 
            Department                     = $User.Department
            Description                     = $User.Description
            Office                              = $User.Office
            OfficePhone                   = $User.OfficePhone
            StreetAddress                = $User.StreetAddress
            POBox                            = $User.POBox
            City                               = $User.City
            State                            = $User.State
            PostalCode                 = $User.PostalCode
            Title                            = $User.Title
            Company                    = $User.Company
            Country                      = $User.Country
            EmailAddress               = $User.Email
            AccountPassword        = (ConvertTo-SecureString $User.Password -AsPlainText -Force) 
            Enabled                      = $true
            ChangePasswordAtLogon      = $true
        }   #end userprops   

         New-ADUser @userProps

    } #end else
```

first error was about path so i changed it like this
changed path = $user.path to path = $user.ou
than i got this error

```
New-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again. At line:43 char:21 + New-ADUser @userProps
```

so i changed Name = $user.name to Nam = $User.sAMAccountname and then got this one

```
New-ADUser : The specified account already exists
At line:43 char:10
```

i realy dont undrestand about coding and power shell can some one help me to figure this out ?

Comment: The error message is clear, meaning it is just a matter of troubleshooting in your environment: add some checks to your script, e.g. add `Write-Host 'User name:' $User.sAMAccountname` and check if the username returned really exists: `Get-AdUser $ReturnUserName`

Comment: The script you found uses a lot of csv fields that are not in your csv file.. Make sure the fields you do not have are not used by the code and where the headings in your file do not match the headings used by the code you should adjust your input file or the code (like with field heading `SN` in your file, but `Surname` used in the code)

Comment: if your password is the same for all accounts, then replace your `ou` field in your csv by `Path` (and verify you `sn` - need tou be `surname` as @Theo pointed out), then one line is enough : `Import-Csv  C:\Projects\Users\Google2.csv | New-ADUser -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true` (all parameters accept values by propertyname, and the csv get them). Obviously, you will still get an error if an user already exists